# Convert string to slice of string type

Tags: go

In the code below when I inspect `s[i]` it gives me binary numbers instead of characters. Code still works but how can I get `s[i]` to return a character, while still using s type string as parameter?

```
func main() {
    
        var ip string
        fmt.Println("Enter string:")
        fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &ip)
        ip = strings.ToLower(ip)
        fmt.Println(isP(ip))
    }
    //Function to test if the string entered is a Palindrome
    
    func isP(s string) string {
        mid := len(s) / 2
        last := len(s) - 1
        for i := 0; i < mid; i++ {
            if s[i] != s[last-i] {
                return "NO. It's not a palindrome."
            }
        }
        return "YES! You've entered a palindrome"
    }
```

Comment: Characters _are_ numbers. You should use a slice of `rune`s though.

Comment: Just use the `string()` function. `string(s[i])` returns the character.

Comment: can any of you write an answer? @tkausl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func isPalindrome(s string) bool {
    s = strings.ToLower(s)
    r := []rune(s)
    mid := len(r) / 2
    last := len(r) - 1
    for i := 0; i < mid; i++ {
        if r[i] != r[last-i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    var s string
    fmt.Println("Enter string:")
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &s)
    fmt.Println(s, isPalindrome(s))
}
```

Output:

```
Enter string:
123
123 false
Enter string:
121
121 true
Enter string:
abba
abba true
Enter string:
世界世
世界世 true
```

A Go character `string` is a UTF-8 encoded sequence of characters. UTF-8 is variable length character encoding. `s[i]` is a byte not a character. A `rune` (code point) is a character. Use `string(r)` to convert a `rune` to a printable `string`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "Hello, 世界"
    for _, r := range s {
        fmt.Print(string(r))
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, 世界
```

References:

[Unicode - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)

[Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to convert `string` to a `[]string` you can also just use `strings.Split(s,"")`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above this in the comments, you can use `string(s[i])` to convert it to a character or you can use `fmt.Printf("%c", s[i])` to print the character represented by the corresponding Unicode code point.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string() to return the character.

example : `fmt.Println(string(s[i]))`